Compare two strings containing html tags with same attributes but different orders using C#
I'd like to compare between two strings having html tags in different orders.
Example:
string str1="""<p><strong style="font-size: 36px; color: rgb(153, 51, 255);">Hello </strong><em><u>World</u></em></p>""";

string str2="""<p><strong style="color: rgb(153, 51, 255); font-size: 36px;">Hello </strong><em><u>World</u></em></p>""";

I care about the text as well as the style so I want the result of the comparison to be identical because it gives the same text with the same html result. However, a normal string comparison gives that the two strings are different.
how can I compare these two strings using c# not javascript.

IEquatable<> to compare two objects.

Find a parser that knows about html and gives you a structured comparable view on that.  HtmlAgilityPack might help. But there might be others

Maybe something like:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11454/A-word-wise-HTML-text-compare-and-merge-engine

What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? As a gentle reminder SO is not a free coding service.

The strings aren't equal even if the HTML interpretation is the same. You need to parse the two HTML snippets using eg HtmlAgilityPack and compare the results. You need a parser that can understand the contents of style, not just the tags

to compare the 2 string you have to make few steps:

you need to reorder the attributes of the html tags in both string in the same order.
you need to order the values inside some attributes that takes multiple values like style
trim the text value

to do that you first need to add nuget package HtmlAgilityPack,
here is sample code
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string str1 = "<p><strong style=\"font-size: 36px; color: rgb(153, 51, 255);\">Hello </strong><em><u>World</u></em></p>";
        string str2 = "<p><strong style=\"color: rgb(153, 51, 255); font-size: 36px;\">Hello </strong><em><u>World</u></em></p>";

        bool areIdentical = AreHtmlStringsIdentical(str1, str2);
        Console.WriteLine($"The HTML strings are identical: {areIdentical}");
    }

    static bool AreHtmlStringsIdentical(string html1, string html2)
    {
        var doc1 = new HtmlDocument();
        doc1.LoadHtml(html1);
        var doc2 = new HtmlDocument();
        doc2.LoadHtml(html2);

        string canonicalHtml1 = GetCanonicalHtml(doc1.DocumentNode);
        string canonicalHtml2 = GetCanonicalHtml(doc2.DocumentNode);

        return canonicalHtml1 == canonicalHtml2;
    }

    static string GetCanonicalHtml(HtmlNode node)
    {
        if (node.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text)
        {
            return NormalizeWhitespace(node.InnerText);
        }

        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append('<').Append(node.Name);

        var sortedAttributes = node.Attributes.OrderBy(a => a.Name);
        foreach (var attribute in sortedAttributes)
        {
            string value = attribute.Value;
            if (attribute.Name == "style")
            {
                value = NormalizeStyleAttribute(value);
            }
            builder.Append(' ')
                   .Append(attribute.Name)
                   .Append("=\"")
                   .Append(NormalizeWhitespace(value))
                   .Append('"');
        }
        builder.Append('>');

        foreach (var child in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            builder.Append(GetCanonicalHtml(child));
        }

        builder.Append("</").Append(node.Name).Append('>');

        return builder.ToString();
    }

    static string NormalizeWhitespace(string input)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input.Trim(), @"\s+", " ");
    }

    static string NormalizeStyleAttribute(string style)
    {
        var styles = style.Split(';')
                          .Select(s => s.Trim())
                          .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                          .Select(s =>
                          {
                              var parts = s.Split(':');
                              return new
                              {
                                  Name = parts[0].Trim(),
                                  Value = parts.Length > 1 ? NormalizeWhitespace(parts[1].Trim()) : ""
                              };
                          })
                          .OrderBy(s => s.Name)
                          .Select(s => $"{s.Name}: {s.Value}");

        return string.Join("; ", styles) + (styles.Any() ? ";" : "");
    }
}


Without the code this is a bad answer. That fiddle can go away at any time. Post the code in the question itself

@PanagiotisKanavos you are correct, I changed my answer and I included the code

I've tried this solution and It solves my problem. thank you so much
